# Value is not properly showing in table body in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

[Need output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRCSc.png). The headers are dynamic and body is not rendering properly. please help me to fix it.

here my code:

```html
{
data?.show &&
<th className="text-center" key={index}>
<td colSpan={data?.st && data.st.length} style={{ border: "none" }}>
    {data.label}
</td>
<tr className="p-0">
    {
    data?.st?.map(sub => {
    return (
    <td style={{ borderColor: "black" , fontWeight: "400" }}>
        {sub}
    </td>
    )
    })
    }
</tr>
</th>
}

<tbody>
    {
    res.datas && res.datas.map((ele, index) => {
    var eles = Object.values(ele);
    return (
    <>
        <tr key={index}>
            <td align="center">{1 + index}</td>
            {
            eles.map(dt => {
            return (
            <td align={typeof (dt)==="string" ? "left" : "center" }>
                {dt}
            </td>
            )
            }
            )
            }
        </tr>

    </>
    )
    })
    }
</tbody>
```

But I got output like this.[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fys8V.png) The expected output is added in the top.

Comment: Hi) you have a lot of issues there, check the docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table
first replace <th> with <thead>, next move <td> under <tr>, last - ensure that data for the headers have the same length as for the data rows